# How to assign variable to json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

'I'm trying to assign a variable from a parent div to the json string of a child table and can't seem to get my javascript straight.

What I'd like to see, or some variation of:

```
{"blocks":[{"id":"115",courses:[{"Semester":"S,F","Credits":"3","Subject":"ACT"}‌​, {"Semester":"F","Credits":"6","Subject":"CSI"}]}]
```

And the jQuery I have so far.

```
$('#update').click(function (e){
    var table = $('#table').tableToJSON();
    var blockId = $('#table').closest('div.Block').attr('id');
    table = {"block":table};
    document.getElementById('courseList').value = JSON.stringify(table);
}
```

I'm not sure how to add in the variable that I need in the object? How would I insert blockId?

Comment: Typo `$('#table)` change it to `$('#table')` .you forgot to close  quotes

Comment: Where's the variable you're trying to add again?

Comment: And where exactly should blockId be inserted ?

Comment: In the question, the `115` would be where the id would be. Or take out `block` and just have the id. something like `115=[...]`

Comment: That's not valid JSON, you can't have a `=`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming bracket notation is what you're really looking for :

```
$('#update').on('click', function(){
    var table   = $('#table').tableToJSON();
    var blockId = $('#table').closest('div.Block').attr('id');
    var table2  = {};

    table2[blockId] = table;

    $('#courseList').val( JSON.stringify(table2) );
});
```

Comment: Well yes that will work. But now you have me curious as to how I would make this valid JSON?

Comment: If the `tableToJSON()` method creates an object, that's not an issue, it would be valid JSON once the object is stringified. If the `tableToJSON()` method creates a string and not an object, you have to parse it with `JSON.parse()` before working with it.

Comment: Would something like 
`    {"blocks":[{"id":"115",courses:[{"Semester":"S,F","Credits":"3","Subject":"ACT"},
               {"Semester":"F","Credits":"6","Subject":"CSI"}]}]` be more along the JSON format?